# How do you upload your project to google project hosting from Netbeans?

Tags: svn, project-hosting

Can someone tell me how I can upload my project to google project hosting using Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this url:
http://dupyshon.com/kylanrobinson/blog/2008/10/google-code-svn-and-netbeans/

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded a client and did as in the post.